# Nginx Redirect depending upon user input with POST requests

Tags: nginx, redirect, 301-redirect

I have two Data centers and within each there are multiple servers and database servers.

These servers are hosting specific of some company ID's. I want to redirect my users depending upon the company ID submitted by user (using POST).

suppose my URL is : http://mywebsite.com?companyid=3433(but using POST)

and within my nginx I read the company ID and redirect the request (the Requests can be GET, POST, PUT, DELETE etc)..

suppose the request is with company id=3433, it should redirect the user to http://server02.mywebsite.com/companyid=3433(using POST)..

I am new to nginx. please let me know if anyone has any solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's disallowed to 301 redirect POST by HTTP standards - you can 301 redirect only GET and HEAD.

However, you can use proxy_pass or 307 instead.

Comment: do you have any sample or example code to which i can refer..

Comment: Ok, I have deepened in this problem, and it seems, I was wrong. You can easily redirect all kinds of requests with 307 or proxy_pass, but you can not distinguish them by POST arguments - only by request uri string, i.e. GET requests.